# How to allow 'Unsafe code' in Rider for Mac version?

Tags: c#, macos, unsafe, rider

[image][image]I don't know if I can turn on this option when using Rider 2017.2.1 (Mac version). Anyone could advise? I cannot find that option displayed at all. 
I googled:
To configure properties of project build configurations

In the Solution window, right-click on the desired project and choose Properties.
    In the Project properties dialog that opens, select a project build configuration.
    Edit build properties of the selected configuration as needed and click OK to apply your modifications:

But there is no such option in Mac version at all. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Build_Configurations.html

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution Explorer -> Select your project -> Properties... (alt+enter) -> Select appropriate configuration in "Configurations" section -> Set "Allow unsafe code".

If a checkbox is disabled, wait for Rider 2018.1 EAP 1 will be released. That means the property was imported from some MsBuild targets (it happens in dotnet core projects for example).

[image]

Comment: Hi, I cannot find any appropriate configuration in "Configurations" section, it is blank under "Configurations" section from my view. Could you please give me some detailed steps? I cannot even see the selection "Allow unsafe code". Thanks a million!

Comment: Aga, see the image above =)

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for that. I really appreciate your kind effort. I get it now!

Comment: Not a problem =)