# How to allow unsafe code in JetBrains Rider?

Tags: c#, ide, rider

I want to allow unsafe code in JetBrains Rider 2020.2.4 for linux. I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48154694/how-to-allow-unsafe-code-in-rider-for-mac-version), but the instructions do not seem to apply to this version of the application. How can I allow unsafe code in JetBrains Rider and get rid of the `'unsafe' context is redundant` message?

Answer (score 0):

Solution Explorer -> Select your project -> Properties... (alt+enter) -> Select appropriate configuration in "Configurations" section -> Set "Allow unsafe code".